# Differential of the deviatoric tensor

Tags: derivatives, tensors

Given the relation:
$$\pmb{S} = \pmb{T} + p\pmb{I} \\
p = -\frac{1}{3}tr\mathbf{T}$$
$\pmb{T}$ is the Cauchy stress tensor, $\pmb{S}$ is the deviatoric stress tensor, $\pmb{I}$ is the identity tensor and $p$ is the mean stress. 
How to derive the differential of the deviatoric stress tensor:
$$\frac{\partial \mathbf{S}}{\partial p}$$Is the answer zero tensor? (If the question is not clear enough, please tell me...)

Comment: The equation for $p(T)$ is irrelevant. The derivative is simply $\frac{\partial S}{\partial p} = I$. Now if the question had been to find $\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}$ there would be some ambiguity, and the equation for $p(T)\,$ _might_ be necessary.

Comment: @greg Thank you for your comment. Actually the origin problem is to derive the $\frac{\partial \eta}{\partial p}$, where $\eta= \frac{S}{p}$, and the answer seems to be $\frac{\eta}{p}$, therefore I can not understand how to get that answer. I think you are right, maybe I need to check that again.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the answer is a zero tensor,
because of the following reasons.
Tensor space is also a vector space.
The inner product between an isotropic tensor and
a deviatoric tensor or a trace-less symmetric tensor
is zero, i.e. $\boldsymbol I:\boldsymbol S=tr(\boldsymbol S)=0$,
and the two tensors are orthogonal. 
Therefore, the isotropic tensor field and the traceless symmetric tensor field are independent.